# Many to many relation for same rank tables

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

For example I have online store with `keyboards` and `mouses` tables. And on the product(keyboard or mouse) page I want to show `Recommended to buy with...` section where other product (keyboard or mouse) will appear. So on Keyboard#1 page may be recommended Keyboard#2 and Mouse#1, that means on Keyboard#2 and Mouse#1 pages will be recommended Keyboard#1.

The main question is, can I get by with one table?

I thought something about many to many (Polymorphic) relation but I am not sure if this will work.

Below is a rough scheme of what I think about right now:
**Tables:**
keyboards

- id
- number_of_keys

mouses

- id
- is_wireless

associations

- product_1_associatable_id
- product_1_associatable_type
- product_2_associatable_id
- product_2_associatable_type

**Models:**
Keyboard

```
public function associations()
{
  return $this->morph...?('associatable');
}
```

Mouse

```
public function associations()
{
  return $this->morph...?('associatable');
}
```

**Upd:** It's ok if there will be several relations but still only 1 table e.g. `associated_keyboards` and `associated_mouses` relations

Comment: Are you going to have more product types e.g. monitors etc? If yes then you need to think of polymorphic relationships. Otherwise you might be able to get away with regular relationships between just these two.

Comment: @Coola yea, it's highly likely there will be more products

Comment: Also will each product have many recommendations or only one?

Comment: @Coola many recommendations

Comment: Sorry to break up the questions but will each product also have a unique identifier like an SKU or something? Then you could hold the SKU as a separate table and have the SKU table as a polymorphic many to many relationship.

Comment: @Coola no, there is no unique identifier for products unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231114/discussion-between-coola-and-hehoboy).